# Log4j2 does not write to log file, nor does it create it

Tags: log4j2

I know the question has been asked before, however I still can't get log4j2 to write to a file (the file is not even created). It does display on the console however.

I have placed log4j2.xml in src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="error.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My main method, which invokes the logging function

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApplication1 {


    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SpringApplication1.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication1.class, args);
        logger.info("testing info");
        logger.error("this is an error");

    }
```

I have these two dependencies in my pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring-jcl` needs to be on the classpath.

Spring Boot's default logging mechanism is logback.

One way is to use the [Spring Boot Log4j starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging). To use log4j, logback should be excluded:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```